# Simple Function with Umbraco and Image Processor has stopped after upgrade

Tags: umbraco, imageprocessor

I'm maintaining an Umbraco site which contains a simple watermarking feature implemented in Image Processor. This is working in Umbraco 7.4.2, via a compiled library for which I do not have the source. After updating Umbraco to 7.12.3 it no longer works. I'm looking for a simple explanation or hints on what the cause may be.

The versions of ImageProcessor and ImageProcessor.Web are unchanged (2.6.2.25 & 4.9.3.25) and ImageProcessor.Web.Config (2.4.1.19) are unchanged.

It would appear to be implemented an entry in the 
\config\ImageProcessor\processing.config file as follows:

```
<processing preserveExifMetaData="false" fixGamma="false" interceptAllRequests="true">
<presets>
</presets>
<plugins>
<plugin name="SecurityWatermark" type="MMUmbracoLibrary.Imaging.Web.Processors.SecurityWatermark, MMUmbracoLibrary">
  <settings>
    <setting key="WatermarkVirtualPath" value="~/app_data/watermark.png" />
    </settings>
```

Looking at the library with DotPeek I see the source of the method is as follows:

```
    using ImageProcessor.Processors;
    using ImageProcessor.Web.Processors;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    namespace MMUmbracoLibrary.Imaging.Web.Processors
    {
      public class SecurityWatermark : IWebGraphicsProcessor
      {
        private static readonly Regex QueryRegex = new Regex(".+", RegexOptions.Compiled);

        public SecurityWatermark()
        {
          this.Processor = (IGraphicsProcessor) new MMUmbracoLibrary.Imaging.Processors.SecurityWatermark();
        }

        public Regex RegexPattern
        {
          get
          {
            return SecurityWatermark.QueryRegex;
          }
        }

        public int SortOrder
        {
          get
          {
            return 0;
          }
          private set
          {
          }
        }

        public IGraphicsProcessor Processor { get; private set; }

        public int MatchRegexIndex(string queryString)
        {
          return this.SortOrder;
        }
      }
    }
```

Also this code from DotPeek is the probably most significant part:

```
namespace MMUmbracoLibrary.Imaging.Processors
{
  public class SecurityWatermark : IGraphicsProcessor
  {
    public object DynamicParameter { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Settings { get; set; }

    public Image ProcessImage(ImageFactory factory)
    {
      IMedia mediaByPath = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MediaService.GetMediaByPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.Path);
      if (mediaByPath == null)
        throw new HttpException(404, "No image found");
      if ((int) mediaByPath.Properties["disableWatermark"].Value != 0)
        return factory.Image;
      string filename = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(this.Settings["WatermarkVirtualPath"]);
      ImageLayer imageLayer = new ImageLayer()
      {
        Image = (Image) new Bitmap(filename),
        Opacity = 100,
        Size = factory.Image.Size
      };
      return factory.Overlay(imageLayer).Image;
    }
  }
}
```

To be honest this code doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but it seems to work. Can anyone suggest how an upgrade of Umbraco could have caused this to stop working?

Comment: reading into the documentation a little i can see that between version 7.4 and everything above there have been changes to the permissions model, and so it is necessary for me to add enabled="true" to use some of the built in functions, I am thinking that this is the same issue for the custom function however it is still not clear to me how to explicitly give permission to this custom function to allow it to run

Comment: sadly just adding allow="true" doesn't change much, anyone know what needs to be done to allow this function to run again?